# "Ad Choices" text from Adsense displaying outside of div

Tags: css, wordpress, adsense

I have a tough problem that I've been trying to solve for the past couple of days. Occasionally the Adsense ads on my site will display the "Ad choices" logo outside of the div instead of in the corner of the ad itself like it's supposed to. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8531/8464557562_836bdb2910_b.jpg

You can see the "AdChoices" logo right above the "contact" nav menu item. Weird right? Has anyone ever seen this before? Any help would be much appreciated!

The website is www.hungryrunnergirl.com but this problem is tough to diagnose because it doesn't happen every time. I have to sit on the site and refresh several times before I can get the problem to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Set the "advert" into text-align=center; in css also set the height

Comment: Hmmm I made the changes you suggested with no luck. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks for your help.